# How to define array properties when importing data with neo4j admin?

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I saw the introduction in the neo4j official website tutorial:[image]
So I try this: targetFramework:string ->targetFramework:[string]

But the error is given:[image]
What should I do to import data correctly?

Thank you very much for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be: `string[]`.